# Quartz trigger creation in large numbers

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Our project is in airline domain and our system is managing the flights for an airline. The system get the flight details from external source as messages and we will always have flights up to 90 days in future in our DB.

We have a requirement to send a message to external system, X minutes before the departure time of a flight. For example 90 minutes before the departure of a flight, a message need to sent to external system. This need to happen for all the flight for a day.

We are planning to implement the solution like when a flight message comes into our system , we will create a quartz trigger for that flight to send the message 90 minutes before its departure time.

But the problem we are facing is there will be more than 300 flights in a day. That means at least 300 triggers are created in system for a single day and we think it will lead to any performance bottlenecks in the scheduler system.

Please suggest if there is any better alternate for this solution. Whether we can achieve it by just one trigger which will query database in frequent intervals and do the complex logic of sending flight message for all flights which satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the issue and posting it here so that somebody else can benefit from it.
Creating large number of quartz triggers is not at all a good idea and we resolved the issue just with two jobs.
The first job will run daily once at midnight and it will find all the flights for that day and calculate its message sending time. This information is written to a table.

Another job is created that runs every five minutes and read the table and see if any message need sent for for the current time and also any failed ones in previous attempt. Then it will send the message and update the status accordingly.